# What does this arithmetic expression mean: A += B++ == 0 in C++;

Tags: c++, arithmetic-expressions, post-increment

I came accross this expression, and can't understand the meaning of line 3 in the following snippet:

```
int A=0, B=0;
std::cout << A << B << "\n"; // Prints 0, 0
A += B++ == 0; // how does this exp work exactly? 
std::cout << A << B << "\n";  // Prints 1, 1
```

A adds B to it, and B is Post incremented by 1, what does the "==0" mean?

Edit:
Here's the actual code:

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstringKDistinct(string s, int k) {
    int ctr[256] = {}, j = -1, distinct = 0, maxlen = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
        distinct += ctr[s[i]]++ == 0; // 
        while (distinct > k)
            distinct -= --ctr[s[++j]] == 0;
        maxlen = max(maxlen, i - j);
    }
    return maxlen;
}
```

Comment: Means your CS teacher is teaching you the wrong things the wrong way. Supplement your formal education with these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It means compare the last value - the `B++` result - against 0 and return a boolean true / false. But this is fairly silly code.

Comment: This is code that if you wrote it in a job situation you should be immediately fired.

Comment: Read about c++ operators and their execution order. This example is confusing but unambigous if you know how this operators work.

Comment: `<< <<` doesn't look like valid C++. Did you mean `<< " " <<`?

Comment: @Lundin Yes that was a typo. Corrected it now. Thanks.

Comment: Though I'm surprised that C++ allows arithemtic with `bool`. I can see how this code would compile clean in C, but g++ with C++14 lets it through as well.

Comment: @Lundin bool will just get promoted to int; in the same way int will be promoted to long etc.

Comment: @UKMonkey Oh right. Silent promotion from `bool` to `int`. Eww. That's even worse than "int booleans" in C. Just eww.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
B++ == 0
```

This is a boolean expression resulting in `true` or `false`. In this case the result is `true`, `true` is then added to `A`. The value of `true` is `1` so the (rough) equivalent would be:

```
if(B == 0)
  A += 1;
++B;
```

Note that this isn't particulary good or clear to read code and the person who wrote this should be thrown into the Gulags.

Comment: Maybe you should precise that B is beeing incremented after the comparaison, which explains why B++ == 0 is true

Comment: @souki Added a rough equivalent to make it easier to understand.

Comment: So when this line is executed, it checks if B==0, adds 1 to A if true, then increments B?

Comment: have an upvote for suggesting a punishment for the person who wrote this.

Comment: @Batwoman05 some people define a good programmer as one who can get something done in as few lines as possible.  Some people produce rubbish that no one else can understand; including themselves in a week; even if it works.  Others define a good programmer who can produce code that any other programmer can pick up and maintain.  Sure, which you pick is personal opinion .... but if you pick the first you're wrong ;)

Comment: Or a more cruel punishment yet: have them maintain the code.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this expression into pieces: `A += value`, whereas `value = B++ == 0`. As later `cout` suggests, `value == 1`. Why is that? Here is why: `value` is result of comparison of `B++` and `0`, but `++` (increment) operation, when written after operand, is being processed after the comparison, i.e. if you write `A += ++B == 0` the later `cout` should (and does) print `0, 1`.